# Click event not raising on clicking span item which added dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
<div class="content todo-card">

</div>
```

To the above div item i add below div items dynamically . I want to raise an event when click on the span item how i can achieve?

```
<div class="todo-task">
              <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked="yes" />
              <label for="checkbox1">Hello every one <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span>
              </label>
            </div>
```

I tried below code but it didn;t worked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.todo-remove', function () {
             alert('deleleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee');

        });
```

Comment: You're `.todo-remove` element is empty?

Comment: <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> this is my span tag. using below  code but didn't worked.                                                                  $(document).on('click', '.todo-remove', function () {
             alert('deleleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee');

        });

Comment: If you have nothing inside it, there's nothing you can click on. Edit: Unless one of the classes adds content to it, like an icon or something.

Comment: You need to add something in span or you need to give at least height width through css check demo its working https://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/ybLrmc6c/

Comment: Actually that span tag adds a icon. want to raise an event when i click that

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your span element "todo-remove" not yet exists when your code try add onclick event.
You need to add reference to run after page load like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".todo-remove").on('click', function () { 
        alert('deleleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, ost all your code, where you add this jquery?

Comment: Code that i shared is actual code. Using ajax to add span elements in the div tag